# AWS Cloudfront with Beanstalk origin - how to avoid redirect to origin

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

On one of my Beanstalk application Cloudfront redirects user to the origin, instead of caching.
Similar to [AWS CloudFront with multiple S3 origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558615/aws-cloudfront-with-multiple-s3-origins), or https://github.com/Wolox/tech-guides/blob/master/infrastructure/docs/aws/docs/cloudfront-eb-configuration.md.
I saw "The most important step is choosing Forward All, cache based on all in the Query String Forwarding and Caching option. When using an EB load balancer as origin, leaving this option on its None option will cause the distribution to redirect requests instead of caching them." suggestion, but Cloudfront behaviour page was updated, and I couldn't find relevant options anymore.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it was simple - Cloudfront has to forward the Host header. I'm curious why it's not a default cache behavior.

From https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-cloudfront-to-forward-headers/:
Under Cache key and origin requests, confirm that Legacy cache settings is selected. If it's not selected, then follow the steps in the preceding section to create a cache policy. If Legacy cache settings is selected, then complete the following:
For Headers, select Include the following headers.
From the Add header dropdown list, select Host.